# Calculating pairwise Euclidean distance between all the rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, euclidean-distance

How can I calculate the Euclidean distance between all the rows of a dataframe? I am trying this code, but it is not working:

```
zero_data = data
distance = lambda column1, column2: pd.np.linalg.norm(column1 - column2)
result = zero_data.apply(lambda col1: zero_data.apply(lambda col2: distance(col1, col2)))
result.head()
```

This is how my (44062 by 278) dataframe looks like:

[image: Please see sample data here]

Comment: Can you try `zero_data.apply(lambda row: distance(*row.values), axis=1)`

Comment: TypeError: ('<lambda>() takes 2 positional arguments but 44062 were given', 'occurred at index 0')  this is the error i am getting

Comment: its for euclidean distance

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) article on how to post a reproducible `pandas` question. You have not provided any samples of data for us to work with.

Comment: @Quicklearner what are the column names in your dataframe are u using in your computation?

Comment: It’s 8,8 and 6,7 and 7,7 and so on based on  bigram

Comment: So between which columns do you want to compute the distance? Between all of them?

Comment: I have this dataframe of 44062 by 278 and I have to find Euclidean distance between users actual data is my user

Comment: If you have 3 users a,b,c then you want to find 3 distances between each of them, a-b, a-c, b-c?

Comment: zero_data = data
distance = lambda column1, column2: pd.np.linalg.norm(column1 - column2)
result = zero_data.apply(lambda col1: zero_data.apply(lambda col2: distance(col1, col2)))
result.head()  
This is giving result based on column in my dataframe but I want row wise

Comment: @Quicklearner so if i understand this user **0** is the row with `index = 0` , user **1** is the row with `index = 1` ... and so-on.. and you want to calculate the `np.linalg.norm` b/w all **user 0** and **user 1**, **user 0** and **user 1**, **user 0** and **user 2**, ... **user 0** and **user n**..

Comment: Yes right you are correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To compute the Eucledian distance between two rows i and j of a dataframe df:

```
np.linalg.norm(df.loc[i] - df.loc[j])
```

To compute it between consecutive rows, i.e. 0 and 1, 1 and 2, 2 and 3, ...

```
np.linalg.norm(df.diff(axis=0).drop(0), axis=1)
```

If you want to compute it between all the rows, i.e. 0 and 1, 0 and 2, ..., 1 and 1, 1 and 2 ..., then you have to loop through all the combinations of i and j (keep in mind that for 44062 rows there are 970707891 such combinations so using a for-loop will be very slow):

```
import itertools

for i, j in itertools.combinations(df.index, 2):
    d_ij = np.linalg.norm(df.loc[i] - df.loc[j])
```

**Edit:**

Instead, you can use [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) which computes distance between each pair of two collections of inputs:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

cdist(df, df, 'euclid')
```

This will return you a symmetric (44062 by 44062) matrix of Euclidian distances between all the rows of your dataframe. The problem is that you need a lot of memory for it to work (at least 8*44062**2 bytes of memory, i.e. ~16GB).
So a better option is to use [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

pdist(df.values, 'euclid')
```

which will return an array (of size 970707891) of all the pairwise Euclidean distances between the rows of df.

P.s. Don't forget to ignore the 'Actual_data' column in the computations of distances. E.g. you can do the following: `data = df.drop('Actual_Data', axis=1).values` and then `cdist(data, data, 'euclid')` or `pdist(data, 'euclid')`. You can also create another dataframe with distances like this:

```
data = df.drop('Actual_Data', axis=1).values

d = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(df.index, 2), columns=['i','j'])
d['dist'] = pdist(data, 'euclid')


   i  j  dist
0  0  1  ...
1  0  2  ...
2  0  3  ...
3  0  4  ...
...
```

Comment: How will I get 44062 by 44062 matrix after calculating Euclidean distance

Comment: How will I get 44062 by 44062 values from this dataframe if I drop actual data

Answer (score 2):

Working with a subset of your data for eg.

```py
df_data = [[888888, 3, 0, 0],
 [677767, 0, 2, 1],
 [212341212, 0, 0, 0],
 [141414141414, 0, 0, 0],
 [1112224, 0, 0, 0]]

# Creating the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Actual_Data', '8,8', '6,6', '7,7'], dtype=np.float64)

# Which looks like
#     Actual_Data  8,8  6,6  7,7
# 0  8.888880e+05  3.0  0.0  0.0
# 1  6.777670e+05  0.0  2.0  1.0
# 2  2.123412e+08  0.0  0.0  0.0
# 3  1.414141e+11  0.0  0.0  0.0
# 4  1.112224e+06  0.0  0.0  0.0

# Computing the distance matrix
dist_matrix = df.apply(lambda row: [np.linalg.norm(row.values - df.loc[[_id], :].values, 2) for _id in df.index.values], axis=1)

# Which looks like
# 0     [0.0, 211121.00003315636, 211452324.0, 141413252526.0, 223336.000020149]
# 1    [211121.00003315636, 0.0, 211663445.0, 141413463647.0, 434457.0000057543]
# 2                 [211452324.0, 211663445.0, 0.0, 141201800202.0, 211228988.0]
# 3        [141413252526.0, 141413463647.0, 141201800202.0, 0.0, 141413029190.0]
# 4      [223336.000020149, 434457.0000057543, 211228988.0, 141413029190.0, 0.0]

# Reformatting the above into readable format
dist_matrix = pd.DataFrame(
  data=dist_matrix.values.tolist(), 
  columns=df.index.tolist(), 
  index=df.index.tolist())

# Which gives you
#               0             1             2             3             4
# 0  0.000000e+00  2.111210e+05  2.114523e+08  1.414133e+11  2.233360e+05
# 1  2.111210e+05  0.000000e+00  2.116634e+08  1.414135e+11  4.344570e+05
# 2  2.114523e+08  2.116634e+08  0.000000e+00  1.412018e+11  2.112290e+08
# 3  1.414133e+11  1.414135e+11  1.412018e+11  0.000000e+00  1.414130e+11
# 4  2.233360e+05  4.344570e+05  2.112290e+08  1.414130e+11  0.000000e+00
```

### Update

as pointed out in the comments the issue is `memory overflow` so we have to operate the problem in batches.

```py
# Collecting the data
# df = ....

# Set this number to a lower value if you get the same `memory` errors.
batch = 200 # #'s of row's / user's used to compute the matrix

# To be conservative, let's write the intermediate results to file type.
dffname = []

for ifile,_slice in enumerate(np.array_split(range(df.shape[0]), batch)):

  # Let's compute distance for `batch` #'s of points in data frame
  tmp_df = df.iloc[_slice, :].apply(lambda row: [np.linalg.norm(row.values - df.loc[[_id], :].values, 2) for _id in df.index.values], axis=1)

  tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(tmp_df.values.tolist(), index=df.index.values[_slice], columns=df.index.values)

  # You can change it from csv to any other files
  tmp_df.to_csv(f"{ifile+1}.csv")
  dffname.append(f"{ifile+1}.csv")

# Reading back the dataFrames
dflist = []
for f in dffname:
  dflist.append(pd.read_csv(f, dtype=np.float64, index_col=0))

res = pd.concat(dflist)
```

Comment: I think the column 'Actual_data' should be ignored in the computations. Also you should take into account that there are 44062 rows in the df, and your solution will be very slow.

Comment: MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-965652f0dca4> in <module>
      1 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
      2 
----> 3 cdist(a, a, 'euclid')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py in cdist(XA, XB, metric, *args, **kwargs)
   2727     out = kwargs.pop("out", None)
   2728     if out is None:
-> 2729         dm = np.empty((mA, mB), dtype=np.double)
   2730     else:
   2731         if out.shape != (mA, mB):

after applying this i am getting the above error

cdist(a, a, 'euclid')

Comment: @Quicklearner you are out of memory, as I wrote in my answer... a 44062 by 44062 array of floats requires at least around 16GB of memory. Use pdist instead which requires half the memory.